# Poly / Bezier curve from a list of coordinates

Tags: python, bezier-curves, import, coordinates

I'm trying to create curves from a list of points, I have the xyz coordinates in text files.
I could make it manually via the python console for a single curve, but I have to do it many times and I don't know how to correctly implement a loop.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 26):

This should work:

```
import bpy

# sample data
coords = [(1,1,1), (2,2,2), (1,2,1)]

# create the Curve Datablock
curveData = bpy.data.curves.new('myCurve', type='CURVE')
curveData.dimensions = '3D'
curveData.resolution_u = 2

# map coords to spline
polyline = curveData.splines.new('NURBS')
polyline.points.add(len(coords))
for i, coord in enumerate(coords):
    x,y,z = coord
    polyline.points[i].co = (x, y, z, 1)

# create Object
curveOB = bpy.data.objects.new('myCurve', curveData)

# attach to scene and validate context
scn = bpy.context.scene
scn.objects.link(curveOB)
scn.objects.active = curveOB
curveOB.select = True
```

Comment: It creates a NURBS curve. The type for `curveData.splines.new(type)` can be chosen from `('POLY', 'BEZIER', 'BSPLINE', 'CARDINAL', 'NURBS')`.

Comment: Thanks, but I already did something similar actually. Is there a way to make it a function that reads the coords from a text file passed as an argument? Something like CreatePolyLine('coords_file_name.txt')...

Comment: If you install NumPy (which comes [bundled with the Linux version](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.5/Source/Python/API/Numpy_Bundle)), you could replace the fourth line with `coords=np.loadtxt('filename.txt')`, and add `import numpy` at the top... otherwise there's certainly other ways to read in a text file in Python.

Comment: Note for anyone who finds this later, if you choose `'BEZIER'` for the `curveData.spline` type you'll need to use `.bezier_points.add()` and `.bezier_points[i].co` instead of `.points.add()` and `points[i].co`.

Comment: For Bezier, the default (0,0,0) handles won't be adequate, you may want to set them to the points as well: `.bezier_points[i].handle_left = .bezier_points[i].handle_right = .bezier_points[i].co`

Comment: I like to set my handles to the adjacent nodes in the list.  That way, if I use the curve as a bezel of something, the end caps and joints will be aligned properly.

Comment: If you get `AttributeError: 'bpy_prop_collection' object has no attribute 'link'` in Blender 2.8 or newer, then check this answer https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/162417/131771