# Import custom file format into Blender

Tags: python, mesh

I have some text files that contain the (x, y, z) values of points that make up a curve. How can I import this curve into blender, add some thickness, and, if possible, color the line by a fourth variable (like time)?

As an example, here is a python script that prints x, y, z and t values for a spiral:

```
import numpy as np

t = np.linspace(0,10,100)

x = np.sin(t)
y = np.cos(t)
z = t

for vec in zip(x, y, z, t):
    print '%.2f %.2f %.2f %.2f'%(vec[0],vec[1],vec[2],vec[3])
```

And the output looks like my data files:

```
0.00 1.00 0.00 0.00
0.10 0.99 0.10 0.10
0.20 0.98 0.20 0.20
0.30 0.95 0.30 0.30
0.39 0.92 0.40 0.40
0.48 0.88 0.51 0.51
0.57 0.82 0.61 0.61
0.65 0.76 0.71 0.71
0.72 0.69 0.81 0.81
0.79 0.61 0.91 0.91
0.85 0.53 1.01 1.01
0.90 0.44 1.11 1.11
0.94 0.35 1.21 1.21
0.97 0.25 1.31 1.31
0.99 0.16 1.41 1.41
...
```

How can I import this data into Blender? (Note: I have used the [3D surface plugin](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Add_Mesh/Add_3d_Function_Surface) to draw lines and surfaces in Blender. This is not what I am asking here. In this case, I don't want to plot an equation, but experimental data from text files.)

Comment: It's easier if you add a `v ` (v and a space) and import it has a .obj

Comment: consider this link http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16366/use-add-3d-function-surface-addon-via-python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One easy solution, though kind of "hacky", would be to append "v " (a lowercase v and a space) to the beginning of each line, and then importing it has a Wavefront .obj format.

So just do: `print "v " + '%.2f %.2f %.2f %.2f'%(vec[0],vec[1],vec[2],vec[3])`

In this example three vertices are defined, then they are automatically assigned an index from top to bottom;

```
v 0.00 1.00 0.00 0.00 #This is the index 1
v 0.10 0.99 0.10 0.10 #This is the index 2
v 0.20 0.98 0.20 0.20 #This is the index 3
```

Then, to define a "face" (a connection of 2 or more vertices) use:

```
f 1 2 3
```

Using this will define a face between the vertices of index 1, 2 and 3.

If, however, you want to only connect vertices with edges, you can use:

```
l 1 2
```

To define an edge between vertices  of index 1 and 2.

If you want a brief explanation, there's a [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file). For the complete specification, refer to [this page](http://www.martinreddy.net/gfx/3d/OBJ.spec).

Comment: This works well to import the individual points. But how do I connect the vertices?

Comment: @DanHickstein There...

Comment: This almost works. I can use f 1/2 2/3 3/4 4/5 ... to connect the vertices. However, the first and the last vertex always get connected in Blender, so the object does not look quite right.

Comment: @DanHickstein Check the answer again; I've specified how to add simple edges.

Answer (score 0):

New Offer
Python Script Screen Capture ...

Please inspect and test and improve and critique if you choose to use.
[image]

The red short curve segments are generated by the python. The color is graduated and repeated.  Substitute your data.
Your browser may allow you to [see image] at full size.

Older Writing

Perhaps you can change your points to a line equation `y = mx + b` and use the same plugin.  Perhaps the plugin has this feature already.

This is a high level description of some steps to be written in Python:

1. Open the file, read the values into some number sequence variable. Print them to the console for inspection.
2. Create or copy a Bezier curve. The curve points are assigned the points from [step 1]. Set the resolution value to 1 and the extrude value to greater than zero.
3. Copy a material and set diffuse value as a ratio of `bias  + (time/maxtime)`.

Certainly a script similar to your needs exists and needs to be found.
Plotting scripts seems like a generally useful category.

Consider inspecting some similar scripts supplied with Blender or elsewhere.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions. My questions was a little unclear and I edited it to reflect that I would indeed prefer a curve defined by these points. I think that your recommended techniques should work, but I don't know enough about blender to know how to make a bezier curve in the terminal. So, I really need a low-level example of how to do this. Thanks.

Comment: @DanHickstein . Does low level mean (01) Blender with Keyboard & Mouse (02) Blender with Python Script?

Comment: I think that it would take a python script.

Answer (score 0):

A good approach to this is listed here: [Poly / Bezier curve from a list of coordinates](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6750/poly-bezier-curve-from-a-list-of-coordinates)

I just use

```
coords=np.loadtxt('filename.txt')
```

to load my datafile and then use the script listed at the above link to add the curve.