# Create 3D tubes from points with Python?

Tags: mesh

Given a series of 3D points, I want to generate a 3D tube with any specified radius. To create many such tubes, I need to do this in Python.

My current plan is to first create a Bezier curve from these coordinates with [the method mentioned here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/6751/30822) and then create a 3D tube from this Bezier curve using [this method](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Tutorials/Modeling/Curves/Making_A_Tube).

Is this the best way of doing this? If not, what is a better way?

Comment: Hi! Just curious if you found a solution for this. I'm new to Blender and trying to script a PVC-related design.

Comment: @richardtallent Hi! That was quite a ride along the memory lane lol, but I don't think I found a better solution than described in the question.