# Can't "curve bevel" imported SVG

Tags: bevel, svg

I'm trying to Object Data Properties > Geometry > Bevel some SVG imported curves, but it doesn't work as expected.

It looks the bevel (either by parameters or Object) are projected in 2 dimensions instead of following the curve as it does with native Bezier or Path curves.

I tryed some solutions like:

- Converting SVG to Mesh then back to Curve, but it creates too many points and I lose the actual curve.
- Setting different types of curve: Poly | Bezier |  Nurbs
- Recalcultating Normals

It may be a noob question but I can only find posts about the [another problem with SVG and the another Bevel function (round/ chanfer edges)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47217/extrude-and-bevel-an-imported-svg-curve).

[image]

Thanks

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91782 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86873 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56344

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Thanks! Your answer solved my problem. Since the SVG was being imported very small, I was scaling it like 100x in XY but keeping it 1x in Z axys. Scaling it equally in XYZ solved the issue. I really appreciate your help. I was a whole week trying to figure this out. Feel free to post it as an answer, although you already are high scored! Thank you, again!

Comment: Hello and welcome. You can instead upvote the answer that helped you.