# Coloring bevel curve with vertex color

Tags: bezier-curves, bevel, vertex-colors

I'm working on a visualization problem.

I'm given a curve with a list of vertices. There is a color assigned to each vertex.

My question is "how do I generate the bevel curve by linearly interpolating the vertex colors?"
Any ideas?
It seems like I need to write some python scripts to achieve this.

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know bezier curve objects can't hold vertex color information, you will likely need to convert to a mesh object eventually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a Python script you can populate a **Color Ramp** in the material according to the color specification. With the curve's **UV coordinates** you can color the bevelled curve with the correct color.

[image: final image]

I start with a manually created *Bezier curve* with its bevel object set and the material assigned, as well as the node tree for the material. It's also possible to [create the whole curve object in Python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/6751/34236), just as I think it's possible to set up the node tree.

[image: material node tree]

In the *Data* tab of the bezier curve under *Texture Space* activate “Use UV for mapping”.

[image: uv mapping setting]

I supply the coordinates of the curve's points and their color values in a *csv* file called `point_data.csv` within Blender. If your files are stored in another format or in an external file, you'll have to [modify the code](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/csv.html) accordingly. Perhaps you might also want to supply the handle positons instead of using auto-handles.

```
x, y, z, r, g, b, a
-1, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1
-2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1
-1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1
2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0
```

This is the script that was used to generate the image above. The coordinate grid was added manually to check if the color positions are correct.

```
import bpy
import csv
from itertools import tee
from mathutils import Vector

material = bpy.data.materials['Material']
ramp = material.node_tree.nodes['ColorRamp'].color_ramp
# Clear the color ramp of all elements but the first
# which can't be removed
for e in reversed(ramp.elements[1:]):
    ramp.elements.remove(e)

# Modify an existing curve object instead of creating new one
curve = bpy.data.objects['BezierCurve']
curve.data.splines.remove(curve.data.splines[0])
spline = curve.data.splines.new('BEZIER')


# Read color info from internal csv file.
# Could also load from external file.
point_data = bpy.data.texts['point_data.csv']
lines = (line.body for line in point_data.lines)
reader = csv.DictReader(lines, skipinitialspace=True)
reader, line_counter = tee(reader)
line_count = sum(1 for line in line_counter)
for i, line in enumerate(reader):
    vals = {k:float(v) for k,v in line.items()}

    ramp_position = i / (line_count-1)

    if i==0:
        ramp_element = ramp.elements[0]
        ramp_element.position = 0
    else:
        ramp_element = ramp.elements.new(ramp_position)
        spline.bezier_points.add(1)

    ramp_element.color = [vals[c] for c in ['r', 'g', 'b', 'a']]

    spline_point = spline.bezier_points[i]
    spline_point.co = Vector(vals[c] for c in ['x', 'y', 'z'])
    spline_point.handle_left_type = 'AUTO'
    spline_point.handle_right_type = 'AUTO'
```

Comment: Fantastic! That's what I want! Thank you so much!